# Evaluating $\int_0^{100}{e^{\{x\}}}dx$ on Desmos

Tags: integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part, desmos

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/u6Y6rbblFek), which shows the following result:

$$\int_0^{100}{e^{\{x\}}}dx=100(e-1)$$

I thought to check the result on Desmos, but it's giving me a different answer! *Note: I am using $\{x\}=x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ as the fractional part of $x$.

Typing the integral directly on Desmos gives $\approx167.93$. I have tried typing in the following into Desmos, which is how the result is done by hand:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{100}\int_{n-1}^ne^{x-n+1}dx$$
and Desmos actually gives the correct answer here, $100(e-1)$.

Is there something that I'm missing or typing incorrectly into Desmos, or is it just wrong?

As a reference, [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zacvdpvtq8) is what I am getting from Desmos.
**_____________________________________________________**

Update: As I was typing the question, I thought to input $\int_0^{k}{e^{\{x\}}}dx$ and $k(e-1)$ into Desmos, and I noticed that the values to start to drift from eachother at around $k=30$. This still doesn't tell me what the issue is though.

Comment: That's an overflow error with Desmos, since it doesn't have intelligence to see that $e^{\{x\}}$ is periodic. Plot $\int_0^x e^{\{y\}}dy$ and $x(e-1)$ to see what happens for $x>40$.

Comment: plotting int_0^x exp(t-floor(t))dt (desmos input) you will see that the plot of the function appears to completely break down for $x>30$ and so my assumption would be (as others have mentioned) that this is a calculation error in desmos, likely to do with how it defines integrals and/or the exponential function

Answer (score 2):

Just note that

$$
\int_{0}^m e^{\{x\}}\,d x=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}e^{\{x\}}\,d x=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_{0}^1 e^{x}\,d x=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(e-1)=m(e-1)
$$

for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Now just compute in a calculator for $m=100$ and you get $100(e-1)\approx 171,8$ so there is something wrong with the computation of $\int_{0}^{100}e^{\{x\}}\,d x$ by Desmos.